# What is indexPath in NSIndexPath

Tags: swift, tableview, nsindexpath

I have this trunk of code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row] //will give us the 0th, 1st, 2nd etc..

    return cell
```

can somebody explain to me what is the "indexPath" in the first line?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/

Answer (score 2):

`indexPath` is the *local* name of the parameter whose *external* name is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

`indexPath` is defined inside the function body (and you do use it), while the function caller has to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when they name the function parameter: `let cell = tableView.delegate.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: ...)`

Compare:

```
func sum1(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

func sum2(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

func sum3(integer a: Int, secondInteger b:Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

sum1(1, b: 2)
sum2(1, 2)
sum3(integer: 1, secondInteger: 2)
```

It is time for you to check Apple documentation about **Function Parameter Names**: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/

They  got  a  got a  good  documentation about  indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

`NSIndexPath` is a sub class of `NSObject`. It represents the path to specific node in a tree of an array collection.

[it has clearly mentioned in here. read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/index.html)

Your question is based on tableView. you have a collection of cells in a table view. So the node is the cell which you select.

`indexPath` represents your selected cell in the tree in here.